# Trouble with htaccess multiple rewrite rules

Tags: php, apache-2.4, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirection

I have a below criteria

If a query string matches `Microwave_Ovens` text I need to replace with `Microwave-Ovens` (replace underscore by hyphen) in Request URI.

It is working as expected for the first set of 3 lines mentioned below. I actually need to do the same for some other type (assume `Vacuum_Cleaners`) also the same. I added second set of 3 lines but it is not working. Whatever I specify first is working only.

My rewrite conditions & rules are as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)Microwave_Ovens(.*)$
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_+([^_]*)$ /Mr10q/$1-$2?%1Microwave-Ovens%2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_+(.*)$ $1-$2 [N,DPI]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)Vacuum_Cleaners(.*)$
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_+([^_]*)$ /Mr10q/$1-$2?%1Vacuum-Cleaners%2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_+(.*)$ $1-$2 [N,DPI]
```

Can anyone please suggest me what I am doing wrong here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)Microwave_Ovens(.*)$
> RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_+([^_]*)$ /Mr10q/$1-$2?%1Microwave-Ovens%2 [R=301,L]
> RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_+(.*)$ $1-$2 [N,DPI]
> ```

Your rules appear to do a lot more than you've stated in the question? But the main problem here would seem to be the second `RewriteRule` directive. The preceding `RewriteCond` directive(s) only apply to the first `RewriteRule` directive. So, the second `RewriteRule` will run unconditionally and catch any request that might contain `Vacuum_Cleaners`.

Since you have duplicated this directive in the second rule block, then maybe simply removing the first one will be sufficent. For example:

```
# 1
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)Microwave_Ovens(.*)$
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_+([^_]*)$ /Mr10q/$1-$2?%1Microwave-Ovens%2 [R=301,L]

# 2
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)Vacuum_Cleaners(.*)$
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_+([^_]*)$ /Mr10q/$1-$2?%1Vacuum-Cleaners%2 [R=301,L]

# 3
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_+(.*)$ $1-$2 [N,DPI]
```

Comment: Thank You so much for your help It worked for me 

For the 3rd rule I have added like the below

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)Microwave_Ovens|Vacuum_Cleaners(.*)$
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_+(.*)$ $1-$2 [N,DPI]